# Xamarin C# - Unable to convert Canadian date format to US date format

Tags: c#, date, xamarin

I am unable to convert Canadian date format(yyyy-MM-dd) to US date format(MM/dd/yyyy).
I am using DateTime.TryParseExact method to convert and I am getting it in format MM-dd-yyyy but not able to replace "-" with "/".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if it work for you...

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

fist convert date of candian formate to DateTime and than make use of tostring like as below

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd//yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Example : try below

```
var dateString = "15/06/2008";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, 
                       "yyyy-dd-MM", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dt);
var date = dt.ToString("MM/dd//yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```